# In how many ways can you sit 10 class eleven students and 14 class twelve students together in a row if no two class eleven students may be adjacent?

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, permutations

> In how many ways can you sit 10 class eleven students and 14 class twelve students together in a row if no two class eleven students may be adjacent?

I have tried it this way:
Since no two students from class eleven can sit together, we can make a 10 pairs of students by taking 1 from class eleven and 1 from class twelve. If we treat those 10 pairs as 10 individual students, we will have 14 individual students to arrange, taking the remaining 4 of class twelve students. As a result we will have 14! permutation.

The answer in text is given $^{15}P_{10} \times 14!$

Do we have to take 10 students from 15 slots in total because if we count each slot at the right of each class eleven students, there are 10 slots, 4 extra slots from the non paired class twelve students, and 1 extra slot because a class twelve student can also sit at the left of the first class eleven student in the row? Is this the reason we take 10 out of 15 instead of 10 out of 14?

Comment: I would prefer to phrase it as "*First arrange the class12 students.  Then, from among the gaps between the class12 students or to the far ends... pick one such gap for the youngest class11 student to be placed.  Then choose another different such gap for the second youngest, and choose another different such gap for the third and so on...*"

Comment: Thank you for your comment.

Comment: Students can be seated in a row or in a circle or other arrangements! I get it that you mean in a row but your question should clarify the arrangement.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First arrange grade $12$ learners in $14!$ ways

Then it will be $15$ spaces, from before first learner to  after last learner

$(1)\text{GR}12,(2)\text{GR}12,(3)\text{GR}12,(4)\text{GR}12,(5)\text{GR}12,(6)\text{GR}12,(7)\text{GR}12,(8)\text{GR}12,(9)\text{GR}12,(10)\text{GR}12,(11)\text{GR}12,(12)\text{GR}12,(13)\text{GR}12,(14)\text{GR}12,(15)$

it can be $^{15}P_{10}$ diffrent arrangements for grade $11$ learners

total number of arrangements is $^{15}P_{10} \times 14!$

Comment: This clears my mind, thank you.